# Capturing Item clicks in listview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm using the following to record what items have been checked in a listview.

```
 Dim Tert As New ArrayList
        For Each item In lvt.CheckedItems
            Tert.Add(item.text)
        Next
        Dim message = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Tert.ToArray())
```

The problem is that its always one item behind. For example when i check the first item it shows blank, then the second item it shows the first item and so on.

I'm hopefully using this as a variable in a OLEDB query for having a dynamic `WHERE` clause so need to be able to capture the clicks

Comment: The LV has ItemCheck and ItemChecked events so there is no reason it needs to be off by one.  Where is that code located?

Comment: Currently its part of a sub that is called when the Checked event is fired. If i add directly to this event with a messagebox it displays blank on the first click (checkbox shows checked when message box is closed). Item Checked gets stuck in a loop of blankness. The aforementioned Sub is also called when a combobox changes value to determine which file to reference to populate the LV

Comment: I have no idea what a "loop of blankness" is, but given the nature of a MsgBox, it is the wrong way to test/debug event code.  Since the LV has a CheckedItems collection, you could do something like:   `String.Join(",", myLV.CheckedItems.Cast(Of ListViewItem).Select(Function(t) t.Text).ToArray)` all at once as part of creating the SQL for a  " WHERE foo IN (1, 3, 89, 187) "

Comment: Thanks, basically as the program loaded it would display a blank message box and clicking OK would just continually reproduce this